# WebView in Fragment in ActionBar-navigated Activity - how to avoid reload?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

So I have an activty with 3 tabs which I navigate between through the ActionBar (SupportActionBar). Each of the tabs has a Fragment with a WebView attached to them, with a TabListener implement as examplified in the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs).

This all works fine, except that the `onCreateView` method of the Fragment is called each time a fragment is reattached. This in turn causes the WebView to either (1) be blank or (2) reload, if I call [restoreState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState(android.os.Bundle)) on it (which I previously have saved manually).

I don't want the page to reload each time the user switches tabs. Neither do I want the scrollbar to reset. Or the HTML forms (if any) to be reset. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by keeping a reference to the `WebView` in the fragment class, and in `onCreateView` I do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mWebView == null) {
        mWebView = new WebView(container.getContext());
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else {
        View parent = mWebView.getParent();
        if (parent != null && parent instanceof ViewGroup) 
            ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(mWebView);
    }
    return mWebView;
}
```